# Refreshing ng-repeat with data from server

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs

Alright so I have the following architecture:

Laravel 4 powered REST api
AngularJS powered frontend

I use ng-repeat to loop over an array of objects.  I also have a form where one fills certain amount of data and Laravel fills in the rest (certain timestamps).  Because the final form of the new data is not defined until the server side, I have to return it and add it to the array of objects in scope.

Here's my **controller:**

```
app.controller('GameCtrl', function ($scope, RestService) {
    $scope.games = [];
    $scope.newGame = {secretcode: ''};
    //debug
    window.scope = $scope;

    $scope.getGames = function () {
        RestService.get('games')
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.games = response.data;
            })
            .error(function (response, statuscode) {
                $scope.flash = 'An error ' + statuscode + ' occurred.';
            });
    };

    $scope.createNewGame = function () {
        RestService.post('games', $scope.newGame)
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.games.push(response.game);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    $scope.getGames();
});
```

Now retrieving data during page reload is not a problem.  The snag I am hitting however is when  creating new game data.  Basically the process goes like this:

**user fills the form and submits**

```
`-> angularjs sends the data to server 

-> laravel 4 adds some new data (timestamps mostly) and creates a new database entry

-> laravel 4 returns the newly created data back to angularjs 

-> angularjs adds the new entry into the array of objects 

-> angularjs refreshes the table generated from the array since there is a new entry`
```

Now I tried using `$scope.$apply()` but this resulted in an error.

So what can I do to make ng-repeat refresh the table correctly?

Comment: Can you post the error you've got when you've used $scope.$apply?

Comment: It says: $digest already in progress

Comment: try wrapping a $timeout with 0 duration, it should handle the $apply automatically error free

Comment: @AlexandrinRus Do you have an example to show?

Comment: Do you want to automatically run getGames() when the server data has been changed? Maybe you could use a pub/sub service, that's what I did.

Comment: @glepretre That sounds very resource intensive to redowownload everything every time an update is done.  Right now what returns from the server is only the updated information.

Comment: hmm... Could you create a simplified plunker/fiddle with a fake RestService?